# SQL Server regular expression to find comma in middle of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code snippet like this

```
, @generalAgency_uniqueID, nvarchar(100)
           , @risk_uniqueID, nvarchar(100)
           , @rsk_transactionType, nvarchar(5)
           , @rsk_transactioneffectivedate, datetime
```

I want to replace only the commas in the middle of each line with spaces using ِSQL regular expressions.

Please help.

Comment: You can use CLR from T-SQL (and therefore the full power of Regex in .net), but it brings in a whole host of other issues and as @GordonLinhoff has shown you don't need it for this

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't really have a regular expression replace functionality.  Although you can try to mimic it, here is a different approach:

1. Replace `', @'` with some unusual sequence
2. Replace commas with sapces
3. Replace the unusual sequence sequence with `', @'`

Something like this:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, ', @', '***WISH I HAD REGEX REPLACE***'
                              ), ',', ' '
                      ), '***WISH I HAD REGEX REPLACE***', ', @'
              )
```

Comment: I meant using the regular expression functionality available in the Find/Replace dialog in Management studio when you write stored procedures or queries. You hit <Ctrl>F and get the dialog and choose "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox and then there's a lot of regex functionality available like $ for end of line etc.